# scanf causing segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My code was working fine. Then I started to get a segmentation fault. I tried flushing the buffer and that didn't work. `scanf` is taking an `int` variable called `frame_size` and this is where I think the problem lies. Can anybody help me clear up this segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char ref[30];      // array that holds reference string
    int frame_size;    // maximum number of frames is 8
    // a frame holds a number thats in the reference stream.  
    int optimal_fault = 0;
    int lru_fault = 0; // least recently used faults
    int mfu_fault = 0; // most frequently used faults
    int lfu_fault = 0; // least frequently used faults    
    int type = 0;      // initializing to an invalid type in the switch statement
    int pages = 0;     //counts how many times you've looped
    //int page = 0;    //this will be the pages array 
    printf(" Please enter reference string: ");

    //fflush(stdin);    
    fgets(ref, 30, stdin);

    printf(" Please enter the number of frames(no more than 8 allowed)\n");

    scanf("%i[^\n]", &frame_size);

    int len = strlen(ref);
    int result = 0;
    int page[len];
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (ref[i] != '0') {
        //page[i] = ref[i] *10 + (ref[i] -'O');
        /* if (ref[i] == ' ') {
            i++;
        }*/
        if (ref[i] != ' ' && ref[i+1] != ' ') {
            page[k] = ref[i] - '0' + (ref[i+1] - '0');  
            printf("page: %d", page[k]);
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        //printf("This is the string and number of frames: %d %i ", page[2],frame_size);
    }
    int frame[frame_size];// initializing frame array
    for (int i = 0; i < frame_size; i++) {
        frame[i] = -1; //which means the element is empty
    }

    //optimal algorithm
    /* for (int i = 0; i < ref.size(); i++) {
        printf("%d",ref.size());
    } */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `scanf`, use `getline` and then `strtol`/`strtoul`.

Comment: How do you know the problem is `scanf`? Did you run the debugger to narrow it down?

Comment: `page` is defined to have `len` values. However, the loop variable `k` runs unconstrained in the `while` loop and might exceed `len - 1`.

Comment: The while loop will hang if the `ref` string contains a space because `i` will never be increased.

Comment: On the last loop. 'ref[i+1]-'0'' will be handling the NULL terminator.  Is that what you wanted?  Also, you didn't post what was output before the segfault.  Also, no details of debugging done.  Also, have a DCV.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in your code:

`scanf("%i[^\n]", &frame_size);` will not read the remainder of the line until and including the linefeed, to do this with `scanf`, you should write:

```
if (scanf("%i%*[^\n]%*1[\n]", &frame_size) != 1) {
    /* complain about invalid input */
    exit(1);
}
```

But it is much simpler to use `fgets` to read a line and parse it with `sscanf`, especially since the scanf version will not handle non-numeric initial input and you do not test its return value.

You have a typo here:

```
while (ref[i] != '0')
```

To iterating over the contents of string `ref`, you should stop at `'\0'`, the `NUL` byte which is different from `'0'`, the character 0, whose ASCII value is 48.

Furthermore, the conversion from page number expressed in characters to an integer value is not correct here:

```
    if (ref[i] != ' ' && ref[i+1] != ' ') {
        page[k] = ref[i] - '0' + (ref[i+1] - '0');  
        printf("page: %d", page[k]);
        k++;
        i++;
    }
```

You should write this instead:

```
for (i = 0; ref[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (isdigit((unsigned char)ref[i] && isdigit((unsigned char)ref[i+1])) {
        page[k] = (ref[i] - '0') * 10 + (ref[i+1] - '0');  
        printf("page: %d", page[k]);
        k++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

The actual semantics you are trying to implement are obscure, you should document them in a comment before your function.

Also note these recommendations:

- Do not post TAB indented code here, it gets badly formatted.  It is actually a bad idea to use TABs in your code, TAB get expanded differently in different systems and cause your code to become unreadable in various conditions, as here, but also in emails, etc.  I had to reformat your code to fix it.
- Do not comment code blocks with `/* */`, use `#if 0` and `#endif`

Comment: Minor: input like `"123 1"` would not fail `if (scanf("%i%*[^\n]%*1[\n]", &frame_size) != 1)`

Comment: @chux: The semantics the OP is trying to implement are not precisely specified.  The line `if (scanf("%i%*[^\n]%*1[\n]", &frame_size) != 1)` will fail if the user fails to enter a numeric value optionally preceded by whitespace.  The input `"123 1"` will be parsed as the value 123, the rest of the line being ignored.  Whether that is what the OP expects is pure speculation on my part, I guessed that from his bogus `scanf` format `"%i[^\n]"`

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop `while (ref[i] != '0')` ends only when it is not '0' -- what if it never finds a '0' ?

E.g. with an input value of 2312312 the while loop will continue in memory going passed the bounds of page[] writing over the memory.

It could also happen that the condition in your if-statement inside the while loop will never be true if the string starts with two spaces, then i remains == 0

IOW you need to add better error handling starting with the first fgets() and then reading the frame_size checking the range of that.

Then the loop should have another quit condition, for instance

```
for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i+=2)
{
  char s[16];
  if (sscanf(ref + i, "%2[0-9]", s) == 1)
  {
    page[k++] = atoi(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: The code seems incorrect: `123` will be parsed as pages `12` and `23`.

Comment: @chqrlie you are correct, i misread his question, have updated.

Comment: Still not correct: ` 123` will be mis-parsed as `23` instead of `12`.  You should increment by 1 in the loop and skip an extra character if `fscanf` finds a match for 2 digits.  Note that your code will accept numbers with a single digit: we don't know if this is corect. At this point, it is easier to parse by hand.

Comment: @chqrlie  Input like `" 123"` would not set `page[k++]` at all as `sscanf()` would return 0 on first call.

Comment: @chux: `sscanf` will indeed return 0 on first call, then `i` is incremented by `2`, compares less than `3`, and the next call to `sscanf` successfully parses `23` into `s`, and `page[k++]` receives `23`.

Comment: I found out that it was just simply changing the %i[^/n] to %d and it fixed my problems. Thanks guys for all your help!